# In what order are view methods called when transitioning from one view controller to another?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

When I transition from one view controller (let's call it `MasterViewController`) to another (called `DetailViewController`), in what order are the `viewWillDisappear:`, `viewWillAppear:`, etc. methods on each controller called?

I suspect some of the cleanup code called when my master view disappears is interfering with the initialization code in my detail view. I've looked through Apple's documentation but can't find any information involving *multiple* view controllers like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created a simple UINavigationController-based project and added some `NSLog` statements to find out what order they get called in.

1. Master `prepareForSegue:`
2. Detail `viewDidLoad`
3. Master `viewWillDisappear:`
4. Detail `viewWillAppear:`
5. The new view is displayed (with or without animation)
6. Master `viewDidDisappear:` *(after animation is finished)*
7. Detail `viewDidAppear:`

However, when switching between views using a `UITabViewController`, the order is different:

1. SecondTab `viewDidLoad`
2. SecondTab `viewWillAppear:`
3. FirstTab `viewWillDisappear:`
4. The new view is displayed.
5. FirstTab `viewDidDisappear:`
6. SecondTab `viewDidAppear:`

So it seems that you cannot always count on these events occuring in the same order - it can vary depending on the nature of the view controllers you are transitioning between.

Are there any important points that I missed here?

Comment: in case the view controller is being dismissed and has a completion handler it is called after viewDidDisappear. More information here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss 

In the discussion section :)